# от какого класса наследоваться, чтобы можно было BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.name);

Tags: java, android

красным светится `getResources()`, класс ни от какого класса не наследуется.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `abstract Resources getResources()` определен в абстрактном классе `Context`, следовательно, этот метод можно вызвать на объекте класса, в иерархии наследования которого есть класс `Context` (`Activity`, `Service` и т.д.).

Но наследовать класс от `Context` и ему подобных ради получения доступа к методу `getResources()` – идея весьма странная.

Вызвать метод `getResources()` из любого места, можно, например, с помощью класса `Application`.